# Why does NDSolve not give consistent results?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

This is my code:

```
g = 9.81;
\[Rho] = 1.225;
d = 0.04;
AA = Pi*(d/2)^2;
Cd = 0.3;
v0 = 60;
q = 36;

s = NDSolve[{x''[t] == -(1/2)*\[Rho]*AA*Cd*Sqrt[x'[t]^2+y'[t]^2]*x'[t] , y''[t]==-g+(1/2)*\[Rho]*AA*Cd*Sqrt[x'[t]^2+y'[t]^2]*y'[t] , x[0]==y[0]==0,x'[0]==v0*Cos[q],y'[0]==v0*Sin[q]},{x,y},{t,0,11}]
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t],y[t]}/.s],{t,0,10.63}]`
```

I try to solve these differential equations using `NDSolve` and then plotting the result. Yesterday it took me a while to get the graph working right but in the end, I got the graph exactly as expected. This morning I reopen the file to continue working on the project and the graph has completely changed and makes no sense at all. How is this possible? I changed nothing.

What could cause this to happen?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide more information regarding what you are expecting and what you are getting. Do you mean that if you run the code now, you don't get what you expect?

Comment: Even if you have not changed anything, you might have changed the order of evaluation. It is very very unlikely that a simple code as this one executes twice differently.

Comment: YouODE is a particle under the effect of a force and gravity. As the force is small compared to the gravitational force, it makes sense, that the particle will fall down rapidly. And this is what  NDSolve gives you.

Comment: This is a simple 2d simulation of a round object with radius d that is launched with an initial speed v at an angle q. I expect to get a parabola where the ball goes up and to the right and then comes down again. Yesterday I got this exactly, but when I opened the file this morning and ran the code again it gave a really weird graph, it just goes straight down. The thing is that I ran the code yesterday and it worked fine and, I save the file and closed and when I opened it again this morning and ran the code I just do not get the same result.

Comment: To @S.J.E. Huisman .  I think, you mean `q = 36 Degree; `  .